# Windows 8 boot failure, crashed after update

Tags: windows, boot, crash, updates

My laptop - ASUS N53SM

I recently upgraded to windows 8. Everything worked just fine. But when windows updated to one of the updates (cant say exact one), it suddenly crashed. Just after installing updates my computer restarted, and when it should already show my account picture to log on - black screen. Nothing happens. I tried automatic repair, and also windows 8 recovery drive flash disk, where no restore was available, also i didn't have no saved image. Tried some CMD commands in recovery, but with no success. Can you please advise me for this. Im out of luck, cant get my boot work.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of amusement, try power cycling the monitor.  That worked for me on Windows 7 when it hung up like that.  No guarantees however on that one.

Having just come though a Win 7 / 64 bit system ... performing all the possible recovery steps possible AND although having backup but finding them useless during the recovery process (missing a disk driver)....

my only recourse was to reinstall.

One thing of interest, it will basically establish a new c:\windows directory and move your old c:\windows directory to c:\windows.old.  Generally, it will not disturb other things on the disk.  This little feature saved me as I could copy some of my registry settings from the c:\windows.old area to use in the new area.  And data not directly involved with Windows remained untouched.

Good luck...I feel your pain!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try F8 during boot, then Last Known Good Configuration? That usually helps after a bad update. It restores the system to the state it was in during the last successful log on. Either that or you can try using system restore in safe mode as the PC should have created a restore point before it installed the updates, assuming you don't get a black screen when you try to get into safe mode as well.